# Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first

Tags: uitableview, swift3, realm, ios10

My app is terminating due to uncaught exception:

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.

I am new on Realm using Swift 3 and structure also changed in Swift 3.

Below is my code:

```
   #import RealmSwift  

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var todoItem: ToDoItem?

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        todoItem = todos.object(at: UInt(indexPath.row)) as? ToDoItem
    case 1:
        todoItem = finished.object(at: UInt(indexPath.row)) as? ToDoItem
    default:
        fatalError("What the fuck did you think ??")
    }


     let realm = try! Realm() // 1
     try! realm.write { () -> Void in
        todoItem?.finished = !todoItem!.finished
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

   func didFinishTypingText(_ typedText: String?) {
    if (typedText?.utf16.count)! > 0 {
        let newTodoItem = ToDoItem()
        newTodoItem.name = typedText!
        let realm = try! Realm() // 1

        try! realm.write { () -> Void in//
        {
          realm.add(newTodoItem  as! Object)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }  

   class ToDoItem : RLMObject
   {
    /*Every property that should be fetched and stored 
     in the database also needs the dynamic keyword. 
    Also, set the default values for the properties.*/

    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var finished = false

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
     }
  }   

    var todos: RLMResults<Object> {
         get {
             let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "finished == false",              argumentArray: nil)
            return ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)
       }
    }

var finished: RLMResults<Object> {
    get {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "finished == true", argumentArray: nil)
        return ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)
    }
  }
```

/*----------- 2nd View Controller--------*/

```
    import UIKit
    import RealmSwift
    class RealmTableViewController: UITableViewController,AddViewControllerDelegate {

var todos: Results<Object> {
    get {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "finished == false", argumentArray: nil)
        return ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)
    }
}

var finished: Results<Object> {
    get {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "finished == true", argumentArray: nil)
        return ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
    setupNavigationBar()
}

func setupNavigationBar() {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(RealmTableViewController.addButtonAction))
}

func addButtonAction() {
    let addViewController = AddViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    addViewController.delegate = self
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addViewController)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return Int(todos.count)
    case 1:
        return Int(finished.count)
    default:
        return 0
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "To do"
    case 1:
        return "Finished"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = UInt(indexPath.row)

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let todoItem = todos.object(at: index) as? ToDoItem {
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: todoItem.name)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
            cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    case 1:
        if let todoItem = finished.object(at: index) as? ToDoItem {
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: todoItem.name)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
            cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    default:
        fatalError("What did you think ??")
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var todoItem: ToDoItem?

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        todoItem = todos.object(at: UInt(indexPath.row)) as? ToDoItem
    case 1:
        todoItem = finished.object(at: UInt(indexPath.row)) as? ToDoItem
    default:
        fatalError("What  you think ??")
    }


    //let realm = RLMRealm.default()
    //try! realm.transactionWithBlock() {
    //try! realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    let realm = try! Realm() // 1

    try! realm.write { () -> Void in
        todoItem?.finished = !todoItem!.finished
    }
    //}

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func didFinishTypingText(_ typedText: String?) {
    if (typedText?.utf16.count)! > 0 {
        let newTodoItem = ToDoItem()
        newTodoItem.name = typedText!

        //let realm = RLMRealm.default()
        let realm = try! Realm() // 1

        try! realm.write { () -> Void in//
        //try! realm.transactionWithBlock() {
           //realm.add(newTodoItem)
            realm.add(newTodoItem)
       //}
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error, in the `didSelectRowAt` or `didFinishTypingText` method ? Or both ?

Comment: In didFinishTypingText getting error

Comment: Can you please change `class ToDoItem : RLMObject` to `class ToDoItem : Object` and get rid of the `as! Object` cast in your method ? Let's see how it goes with this change.

Comment: Thanks
I am asking that object filter problem Please help.
Sure I accept it.

Comment: Please see my updated response. The last item should solve your filter issue.

Comment: That one is Ok Thanks But I am asking for 

 if let todoItem = finished.object(at: index) as? ToDoItem

Please help me sir

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but surely isn't related to this question. You should open a different question, we're polluting this one with too many different topics.

Comment: OK I will ask different Question.
Thanks to help me 
Tomorrow I will post another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would recommend to start with is :

a) Update Realm to the latest version (2.0.3 at the time of writing), see [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started).

b) make sure you're using RealmSwift and not the Obj-C variant
From the docs :

> The Realm Objective‑C and Realm Swift APIs are not interoperable and using
>   them together is not supported.

Remove all usage of Realm objects starting with `RLM*`.

c) Instead of `try! realm.transactionWithBlock()` use

```
try! realm.write { 
   ....
}
```

d) Query the DB by using :

```
realm.objects(ToDoItem.self).filter(predicate)
```

instead of `ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)`

Comment: func didFinishTypingText(_ typedText: String?) {
        if (typedText?.utf16.count)! > 0 {
            let newTodoItem = ToDoItem()
            newTodoItem.name = typedText!
            
          
            let realm = try! Realm() // 1
            
            try! realm.write { () -> Void in
          
                realm.add(newTodoItem  as! Object)
           
            }
            tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Please update the code in your question please, it's hard to judge an error based on code that's actually not current.

Comment: Now please check it.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why are you still using `RLMObject` in your code. Are you sure you're using RealmSwift ? Do you have an import statement like this `import RealmSwift` at the top of your code ?

Comment: Thanks That problem has solved.
but now New error is
 Cannot convert value of type 'ToDoItem' to expected argument type 'Object'

Comment: Hi
Thanks you almost solved my problem.
But one more error is
'RLMResults' requires that 'Object' inherit from 'RLMObject'

Comment: Please check how you added Realm to your project. You shouldn't deal with `RLM*` objects at all.

Comment: Ok So I am updating one more file Please see it.
There I am not using RLM.

Comment: Now Please check My question I Updated.
Error :- 
Value of type 'Results<Object>' has no member 'object'
I am new so don't know how to remove.
Thanks

Comment: In 2nd View Controller
 In RealmTableViewController -> todos -> ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)
In RealmTableViewController -> finished ->  ToDoItem.objects(with: predicate)

Comment: Please check out the "Queries" section in documentation at: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries. If you want to query objects with predicate you should do something like this: `try! Realm().objects(ToDoItem.self).filter(predicate)`

Comment: OK @Dmitry  I will try it thanks
And  Value of type 'Results<Object>' has no member 'object' error is also coming
See if you please help me.